# Why aren't my links working?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navigation

I have some pretty simple code. The link were working a second ago and now not! (Already checked and emptied cache).

Here's my site: http://claireisabelwebb.com/index.html
The nav bar on the side should go to http://claireisabelwebb.com/experiments.html, etc. The links should turn italic on hover, and a different color after they're visited.

Here's the CSS:

```
/* Link Styles***********************************************************************/

#home_link a:link{
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        color: #330066;  
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 115px;
        font-weight: 100;
        text-align: left;
        letter-spacing: -28px;
}

#home_link a:visited{
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        color: #330066;  
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 150px;
        font-weight: 100; 
        text-align: left;
        letter-spacing: -28px;
}

#main_menu a:link{
        font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 100; 
        color:#336699;
        text-decoration: none; 
        text-align: left;
        letter-spacing:0.2em;
}

#main_menu a:visited{
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 100;
        color:#005522;
        text-decoration: none; 
        text-align: left;
        letter-spacing:0.2em;
}

#main_menu a:hover{
        font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 100; 
        color:#CC0066;
        text-decoration: none; 
        text-align: left;
        letter-spacing:0.2em;
} 

#sec_menu a:link{
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 100; 
        color:#CC0066;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 16px; 
        text-align: left;
        letter-spacing:0.2em;
}

#sec_menu a:visited{
        font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 100; 
        color:#005522;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 16px; 
        text-align: left;
        letter-spacing:0.2em;
}

#sec_menu a:hover{
        font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 100; 
        color:#CC0066;
        text-decoration: none; 
        text-align: left;
        letter-spacing:0.2em;
}
```

And the html:

```
<!-- Main Navigation Menu ______________________________________________-->

    <div id="main_menu" class="main_wrapper_nav_box">
        <div id="sec_menu">
            <div class="main_page_nav_box">
                <a href="Experiments.html">EXPERIMENTS</a>
            </div>
            <div class="main_page_nav_box">
                <a href="writing.html">WRITING</a> 
            </div>
            <div class="main_page_nav_box">
                <a href="photography.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
            </div>
            <div class="main_page_nav_box">
                <a href="graphics.html">GRAPHICS</a>
            </div>
            <div class="main_page_nav_box">
                <a href="artwork.html">ART WORK</a>
            </div>
            <div class="box_sec_nav_ms">
                <a href="artwork.html">Modernist Summer</a>
            </div>
            <div class="box_sec_nav_r">
                <a href="resume/Claire-Webb.pdf">R&#233;sum&#233;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you can solve your problem if it is ok instead of `float:left` in `.main_wrapper_nav_box` change it `relative:position` and add `z-index:1;`

```
.main_page_nav_box{
        display:block;
        position:relative;
    z-index:1;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,.85);
        width:200px;
        text-align: center;
        height: 25px;
        padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
        border:0px ;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-left:10px;
}
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/c7VA4/7/)

hope this help...

Answer (score 1):

Your `#wrapper_text_photo` div is on top of your navigation.  If you re-work that, your navigation will work.

By the way, you can find issues like this yourself by using your browser tools.  I recommend using Google Chrome's developer tools, or Firebug in Firefox, and mousing over the different elements in your page to see what space they are taking up.  You can then remove elements to see the effect real-time.  (See the blue area below)

[image: Debugging Example]

Answer (score 0):

You have `width:1000px;` for `wrapper_text_photo` remove it and see links will work.

```
In style.css line number 132
```

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU - new to this. will you explain why? was it "covering" it?

Comment: @Claire yes it is...take a look at float that will help but be careful as floating divs as they need very sharp css work to make it work across browser.

Comment: @DipeshParmar, `float` is probably the most consistent CSS property there is, from browser to browser.

Comment: @Brad but when template is with tight pixel then we need to maintain every single pixel...including padding margin and etc.

Answer (score 0):

This DIV is and blocking clicks..

```
<div class="wrapper_text_photo">....</div>
```

You can try to put it under the links with CSS..

```
.wrapper_text_photo { z-index: -100;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div with class `wrapper_text_photo` is covering the image.. use a css property: `z-index=-1` for that class